# How to use expect in Bash script and ssh-copy-id

Tags: bash, ssh, expect

From a bash script:

`source ./expect.sh`

I am including a expect code:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/expect <<EOL
spawn ssh-copy-id -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 111.111.111
expect '*?assword*'
send 'thepassword'
interact
EOL
```

And I am getting this:

```
spawn ssh-copy-id -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 111.111.111.111
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
root@111.111.111.111's password:
```

Then I try to connect and I am prompted for a password...

Checking the server, I'm certain no key was uploaded because I would expect to list the "authorized_keys" file:

```
root@server: ls /home/user/.ssh/
known_hosts
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: duplicate: http://serverfault.com/q/727501/30957

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comment about "root":

1. single quotes are just plain characters in expect. use double quotes
2. don't forget to "hit enter" when you send the password

```
expect "*?assword*"
send "thepassword\r"
```

It's generally good practice to quote the heredoc end-word, unless you need to interpolate variables or command substitutions in the heredoc body:

```
some command <<'END'
# .............^...^
...
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You run `spawn ssh-copy-id -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 111.111.111`.
The ip address seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the password prompt: `root@111.111.111.111` that you are
setting up root's key on the remote, i.e. file `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
Either run the script as `user`, not root, or provide an explicit `ssh-copy-id ... user@111.111.111.111`. This allows `user` to login without a password, not root.